# Google App Engine Objectify integration tests

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, junit, jetty, objectify

I've got some junit tests running nicely with objectify.
I'm on

- GAE 1.8.8
- maven 3.1.1
- failsafe-maven-plugin 2.4.3-alpha-1
- jdk 1.7
- jetty-maven-plugin 8.0.1.v20110908

To achieve local persistence mocking, I generally have something like this setup:

```
@ContextConfiguration(value = "classpath*:/test-config.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class PassengerServiceTest {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PassengerServiceTest.class);
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper( new  LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

    @Before
    public void setup() {
      helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
      helper.tearDown();
    }
}
```

However, when I use maven-failsafe-plugin, to run up some integration tests against jetty, then I see the following error:

> **com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException**: Error saving Passenger{id=139, email='will@email.com', firstName='will'}: **No API environment is registered for this thread.**

Now the integration test reads similar to the above unit test, insofar that I setup the LocalServiceTestHelper

I am left thinking that the war file when built, and deployed inside jetty during the pre-integration-test phase does not know about the LocalServiceTestHelper anymore.

Any ideas how to solve this for integration tests using maven-failsafe-plugin ?

Comment: Can you show your pom file?

Comment: I've got the same `SaveException` while trying to use jBehave to test Google App Engine code.  I've called `setUp()` on the `LocalServiceTestHelper` and registered my class with `ObjectifyService.register()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the naming convention of [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes):

which means you integration should be named like WhatEverIT.java ..

```
   <includes>
     <include>**/IT*.java</include>
     <include>**/*IT.java</include>
     <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
   </includes>
```

Comment: Yes, that is in place.